# Composer autoload file before loading dependencies

Tags: function, composer-php

One of the vendor packages I'm requiring exposes a function by autoloading it:

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        ...
        "files": [
            "functions.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it lacks multilingual support.

As I really like the function's fluent definition and I already have a drop-in multilingual alternative., I would like to use my drop-in replacement instead while still using the same function name. Luckily the package has implemented a `function_exists()` check, so I just need to declare my function before the package is autoloaded.

I know I could just reference a `require` before requiring Composer's autoloader, but are there any composer.json alternatives to accomplish this? Is there any way I can tell Composer to load a specific file first, before anything else?

---

More specifically I'm looking to override Laravel's unlocalized `now()` function to a localizable version. Since this question is also applicable to other applications and/or dependencies I kept my question quite generic.